# How to detect that iframe violates CSP

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, safari, content-security-policy

I'm working on an extension, which in injects an iframe with local content to a page. In Chrome it works fine, extensions there are not subjects to Content Security policy.

However it is a problem with some pages in Safari. Therefore I need a way to detect, when the iframe hasn't been injected properly.

Problem is that iframe itself is always inserted (using `appendChild` method), but it's content is not. Even the `.src` attribute remains OK. It seems that `iframe.onload = ...` could do that, but I'd prefer a synchronous call.

Once again, I need a way to either detect CSP violation before the frame was loaded (so no error message is printed), or detect the violation after the insertion itself.

Thanks.